# Exclusing WildFly Modules in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jackson, wildfly, fasterxml

I want to put the following Maven dependency into my project.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency is dependent upon the following:

1. `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0`
2. `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9`
3. `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9`
4. `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0`
5. `joda-time:joda-time:2.7`

I then want to deploy my application to a WildFly 8.2.1 server. While my particular dependency isn't provided by the server, its transitive dependencies are (under `modules/system/layers/base`).

1. `com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/main/jackson-annotations-2.4.1.jar`
2. `com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/main/jackson-core-2.4.1.jar`
3. `com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/main/jackson-databind-2.4.1.jar`
4. `javax/servlet/api/main/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final`
5. `org/joda/time/main/joda-time-1.6.2.jar`

Upon running the application, I get an error due to the `databind` dependency. My `datatype` dependency references a field in `databind` that did not appear in version `2.4.1`. So I need to get the `databind` dependency up to `2.9.9`.

**Idea 1: Manually Include the Dependency**

I tried manually including the updated dependency in my pom as follows (hoping it will override the WildFly version).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Result: Same error occurs.

**Idea 2: Exclude the WildFly Version with jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

I added a `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file with the following contents.

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Result: Same error occurs.

**Idea 3: Change WildFly Module**

I add `jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar` directly to the WildFly module and update the corresponding `module.xml` to use the new JAR.

Result: Works. However, I do not want to do this as I want other developers to be able to use a fresh WildFly install without having to change anything.

**Idea 4: Revert to Previous Version**

I revert my original dependency to be in line with the WildFly versions of `2.4.1` as follows.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Result: Works. However, a bunch of pre-existing code relies on the version being at 2.9.9 so I don't want to go backwards in the versioning.

Why is WildFly ignoring my attempts to override it's module? Is it possible to force the use of `databind` version `2.9.9`. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try excluding the whole jackson modules and provide your own ?

Comment: I tried adding dependencies for all 4 items (annotations, core, databind, and datatype) in my `pom.xml` and the error still occurred. Attempting to use `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with all 4 excluded (in conjunction with these manually added dependencies) also produces the error. So no luck. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?